# htaccess 301 redirect removing html and number

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a tricky redirect and hoping you or someone can help me.

The 301 redirect I need must remove both numbers and ".html", so all the URLs with a number at the end and html.

Example:

Original URL: http://www.domain.com/articles/sampe/2015-05-14/post-name/11234566.html

New URL: http://www.domain.com/articles/sampe/2015-05-14/post-name/

So if the URL has a number at the end and .html, it must redirect.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps

```
RewriteRule ^articles/sampe/([^/]+)/post-name/([0-9]+).html$ http://www.domain.com/articles/sampe/$1/post-name/ [R=301,L]
```

This will 301 redirect all url patterns like `/articles/sampe/XXX/post-name/YYY.html` to `http://www.domain.com/articles/sampe/XXX/post-name/`

**Edit**
Expanding the above rule to work on multiple url patterns containing `post-name` in the url:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/post-name/([0-9]+).html$ http://www.domain.com/$1/$2/$3/post-name/ [R=301,L]
```

This will take all urls in your site like : `/*/*/*/post-name/*.htm` and redirect them to `/*/*/*/post-name/`

The new redirect will work on all urls like these for example:
/articles/somethingelse/2015-05-14/post-name/11234566.html
/posts/category/2015-06-10/post-name/1589.html
/demo/path/folder/post-name/999999.html

Anything that looks like: folder/folder/folder/post-name/number.html

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for the quick response!
Luckily (I think) it only needs to redirect the NUMBER &  HTLM at the end, if it has it, the rest are all variable and harder to add line for each.

Need to rewrite */(thenumber).html, so more rewrite match I think, for those matching with any number and .html = remove/redirect and only keep everything before the number. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TDM well, if you provide us with some different url patterns we can create appropriate rules. The above rule i posted will work on all urls like your example, redirecting them without number.html at the end

Comment: @TDM check my edit in answer. It provides a more general solution.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the edit!

The solution must basically take any URL with a number, length will be different for all so */01010101.html will be redirected to */, the number and .html combination being the trigger/filter?

Comment: @TDM yes. Any url pattern ending in number.html will be affected. Any number length. The edited rule has 2 restrictions. (a) /post-name/ must exists in url and (b) final page in url must have only numbers as name and .html as extension

Comment: awesome thank you!!! I am going to give that  a try and let you know... again, thank you!